# How to set Jquery UI Datepicker date format based on browser language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

I want to set Jquery UI DatePicker date format from browser language, for example if "English (United Kingdom)" in Google Chrome is on top in **Language and input settings...** (chrome://settings/languages) then date format would be **dd/mm/yyyy** and if "English (United States)" is on the top of the list then date format should be **mm/dd/yyyy**. Is there any way to set Date Format from Browser Language in Chrome, Firefox and IE...?

Comment: what do you mean by `browser language`?

Comment: in "chrome://settings/languages", if language is English (United Kingdom) or "en-GB" then date format should be "dd/mm/yyyy" in Jquery DatePicker and if "United States" then "mm/dd/yyyy", I have to set date format based on Browser Preferred or Selected Language...

Comment: You can't reliably tell the format that a user commonly uses for dates from browser settings or values. Far better to use an unambiguous format (e.g. use a month name, not number) or let users specify the format they wish to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would suggest to check the language like

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
// detect browser language but not a decent one 
if (userLang === "en-US") {
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy" );
} else {
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yyyy" );
}
```

**Update:**

I was looking into localization of jQuery datepicker, and here is a [nice discussion](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/automatic-localization-of-datepicker) and  a nice plugin for it.

[**jQuery-localization**](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html), which detects the language and loads the respective regional language for it

```
$.localise('js/jquery.ui.datepicker');
```

> **Note:** *By default, it looks at the locale set for the browser and
>   requests localisations of the specified package based on that*. For
>   example, if the locale is Portuguese/Brazil (pt-BR), it will load
>   js/jquery.ui.datepicker-pt.js and js/jquery.ui.datepicker-pt-BR.js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks good for my case and I can add other languages as well or I could make a separate JS file that would return a date format based on language.

Comment: My browser says "en-us", which might encourage you to present dates as month/day/year. However, that is not what my system settings are. Far better to present dates in an unambiguous format like ISO 8601 or something like *21-Mar-2014* or similar.

Comment: @SohailxIN3N I was also thinking of it.. by only UK and US what about other format..

Comment: Your update description sounds like what I was referring to regarding the language files. They should be part of jQuery UI upon downloading.

Comment: @RobG right.  But each region has it own [default formats](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n) which OP wants to use.  This is purely for the displaying purpose.

Comment: Problem is, when you trust the language files and you trust the client's browser language you assume the client has chosen the  same language for your website. But I, for example, have all my software in english but when I'm on a website and have to choose a language (to buy something ex.) I'm gonna choose dutch, and I will be presented with an english calendar.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Valid point. I think it is purely intensional part of OP who want to it automatically instead of asking the users.

Comment: Many Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me and I think that "Jquery-localization" plugin would be nice solution for that case.

Comment: @Praveen—the point is that using the browser user agent string to determine a user's preferred date format is at best unreliable. Presented with a date like 04/03/06 I have no idea what it means, whether it's using my "regional" format or not. But *04-mar-2006*, *March 4, 2006* and *2006-03-04* are unambiguous and utterly reliable, regardless of what I prefer (which is an unambiguous date format, whatever it is).

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's done in the current project I'm working on. Not sure if it's the best approach as I believe there are language files available in jQuery UI, however ...

```
var cfg = {
    container: '.datepicker',
    regional: {
        nl: {
            closeText: 'Sluiten',
            prevText: '←',
            nextText: '→',
            currentText: 'Vandaag',
            monthNames: ['januari', 'februari', 'maart', 'april', 'mei', 'juni', 'juli', 'augustus', 'september', 'oktober', 'november', 'december'],
            monthNamesShort: ['jan', 'feb', 'maa', 'apr', 'mei', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec'],
            dayNames: ['zondag', 'maandag', 'dinsdag', 'woensdag', 'donderdag', 'vrijdag', 'zaterdag'],
            dayNamesShort: ['zon', 'maa', 'din', 'woe', 'don', 'vri', 'zat'],
            dayNamesMin: ['zo', 'ma', 'di', 'wo', 'do', 'vr', 'za'],
            weekHeader: 'Wk',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''
        }
    }
};

// extracted activation function
$.datepicker.regional = $.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional, cfg.regional);
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional.nl);
this.datepicker.datepicker();
```

So you can add languages in the `cfg` object and choose a custom format.
Only thing left to do is make the language, passed to `datepicker()`, dynamic. Perhaps from the URL, cookie, session, server variable, ... depending on how your project uses languages.

Hope it helps.